# Function in Django model not updating and saving corresponding field

Tags: python, django, django-models

Trying to set-up a function inside the model below to count the length of an `ArrayField` whenever the instance is updated. The function def `total_stocks_calc()` doesn't update the model, it's useless.

```
class Bucket(models.Model):

    stock_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stock_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=6,null=True),size=30,null=True, blank=True)

    objects = models.Manager()


    def total_stocks_calc(self):
        self.stock_count = len(Bucket.objects.get(self.id).stock_list)
        self.save()
```

I'm not getting any errors as well, however this works in django shell: `len(Bucket.objects.get(id=1).stock_list)`, I get the corresponding amount of items within the object.

Would that be the best way to accomplish a Count or Length of total strings within the `ArrayField` known as `stock_list`?

EDIT:

```
    def total_stocks_calc(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.stock_count = len(self.stock_list)
        stock_count.save(force_update=True, update_fields='stock_count')
        super(Bucket, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now I'm playing with this function to help me solve my issue. Still not working as intended however.

Comment: Do you mean to be calling `len()` on the object's `stock_list` attribute rather than setting `self.stock_count` to the length of `self.stock_count`?

Comment: @jidicula, I just fixed that typo error, I'm meant to be counting the total items in `stock_list`.

Comment: What happens if you change the first line of your `total_stocks_calc()` method to `self.stock_count = len(self.stock_list)`?

Comment: @jidicula, that doesn't seem to do anything when I start adding items to a list.